# Python - Pandas: Buy and sell orders split into multiple rows, I want to merge it back into 1 row. So that 1 order = 1 row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, sum

This is buy and sell orders all in the size of 0.02. But they have been split into less pieces and thus each order now occupy more than one row. I want to merge the rows that belong to the same order.

The 'Time' column has unique time-stamp for each order. So looking at that we can see 4 orders

Order 1 is the rows 3, 4
Order 2 is the rows 5, 6, 7
Order 3 is the rows 8, 9
Order 4 is the rows 10, 11, 12

Original DataFrame:

```
| 1| Time      | Market    | Type  | Price    | Amount  | Total     | Fee      | Acc     |
| 2|-----------|-----------|-------|----------|---------|-----------|----------|---------|
| 3| 17:59:31  | Market 1  | Buy   | 1207.55  | 0.0198  | 13.07451  | 0.00989  | MXG 36  |
| 4| 17:59:31  | Market 1  | Buy   | 1207.20  | 0.0002  | 0.013086  | 0.00005  | MXG 36  |
| 5| 15:42:12  | Market 1  | Sell  | 1146.78  | 0.0100  | 3.073645  | 0.00232  | MXG 36  |
| 6| 15:42:12  | Market 1  | Sell  | 1147.44  | 0.0058  | 8.005802  | 0.00746  | MXG 36  |
| 7| 15:42:12  | Market 1  | Sell  | 1147.91  | 0.0042  | 2.000000  | 0.00993  | MXG 36  |
| 8| 12:05:45  | Market 1  | Buy   | 1355.20  | 0.0077  | 7.433008  | 0.00050  | MXG 36  |
| 9| 12:05:45  | Market 1  | Buy   | 1355.00  | 0.0123  | 5.833023  | 0.00755  | MXG 36  |
|10| 10:22:17  | Market 1  | Sell  | 1002.07  | 0.0010  | 0.373225  | 0.00238  | MXG 36  |
|11| 10:22:17  | Market 1  | Sell  | 1001.35  | 0.0055  | 10.00000  | 0.00003  | MXG 36  |
|12| 10:22:17  | Market 1  | Sell  | 1001.20  | 0.0135  | 3.001038  | 0.00330  | MXG 36  |
```

Desired end result:

```
| 1| Time      | Market    | Type  | Price     | Amount  | Total     | Fee      | Acc     |
| 2|-----------|-----------|-------|-----------|---------|-----------|----------|---------|
| 3| 17:59:31  | Market 1  | Buy   | avg price | 0.0200  | 13.087596 | 0.01039  | MXG 36  |
| 4| 15:42:12  | Market 1  | Sell  | avg price | 0.0200  | 13.079447 | 0.01971  | MXG 36  |
| 5| 12:05:45  | Market 1  | Buy   | avg price | 0.0200  | 13.266031 | 0.00805  | MXG 36  |
| 6| 10:22:17  | Market 1  | Sell  | avg price | 0.0200  | 13.374263 | 0.00598  | MXG 36  |
```

So what has been done here is roughly the following:

- The 'Price' column: We can just ignore. Ideally I want to find the
  average weighted price based on the 'Amount' column, but to keep it
  simple lets ignore this for now.
- The 'Type' column: Needs to have the correct value stick to the
  correct order.
- The 'Market' and 'Acc' columns: Have identical value in each rows, so just needs to become 1 row instead of 2-3 rows.
- The 'Amount', 'Total' and 'Fee' columns: Should be sum, adding them
  together

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
df.pivot_table(index= 'Time', values = ['Amount', 'Total', 'Fee'], aggfunc = 'sum')

| 1|           | Amount  | Total     | Fee       |
| 2| Time      |         |           |           |
| 3|-----------|---------|-----------|-----------|
| 4| 17:59:31  | 0.0200  | 'correct' | 'correct' |
| 5| 15:42:12  | 0.0200  | 'correct' | 'correct' |
| 6| 12:05:45  | 0.0200  | 'correct' | 'correct' |
| 7| 10:22:17  | 0.0200  | 'correct' | 'correct' |
```

The 'correct' cells are just to save myself a bit of time (creating the tables were time consuming enough :P). But they show the desired results. But all other columns are missing, including the 'Type' column that had data that had 'buy' or 'sell' data that needed to stick to each order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, I would use `groupby` with a dictionary in `agg` like this:

```
d_agg = {'Market':'first'
        ,'Type':'first'
        ,'Price':'mean'
        ,'Amount':'sum'
        ,'Total':'sum'
        ,'Fee':'sum'
        ,'Acc':'first'}
df.groupby('Time', sort=False)['Market','Type','Price','Amount','Total','Fee','Acc']\
  .agg(d_agg).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
          Time       Market     Type        Price  Amount      Total      Fee        Acc
0   17:59:31     Market 1     Buy     1207.375000    0.02  13.087596  0.00994   MXG 36  
1   15:42:12     Market 1     Sell    1147.376667    0.02  13.079447  0.01971   MXG 36  
2   12:05:45     Market 1     Buy     1355.100000    0.02  13.266031  0.00805   MXG 36  
3   10:22:17     Market 1     Sell    1001.540000    0.02  13.374263  0.00571   MXG 36
```

And you can use `pivot_table` with a dictionary to define how to do aggregations like this:

```
d_agg = {'Price':'mean'
        ,'Amount':'sum'
        ,'Total':'sum'
        ,'Fee':'sum'}

df.pivot_table(index=['Time','Market','Type','Acc'], 
               values = ['Amount', 'Total', 'Fee','Price'], 
               aggfunc = d_agg)\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
          Time       Market     Type        Acc  Amount      Fee        Price      Total
0   10:22:17     Market 1     Sell     MXG 36      0.02  0.00571  1001.540000  13.374263
1   12:05:45     Market 1     Buy      MXG 36      0.02  0.00805  1355.100000  13.266031
2   15:42:12     Market 1     Sell     MXG 36      0.02  0.01971  1147.376667  13.079447
3   17:59:31     Market 1     Buy      MXG 36      0.02  0.00994  1207.375000  13.087596
```

Comment: I don't fully understand how this line is connected:

a) df.groupby('Time', sort=False) ---- b) ['Market','Type','Price','Amount','Total','Fee','Acc']\ --- c) .agg(d_agg).reset_index()

Comment: First off the \ is a line continuation character.  Forgive me, if you already aware of this. If you remove the \ and the carriage return line feed, and make it one continuous line, the syntax will work.

Comment: No I wasn't, thanks :) I suspected it, but wasn't sure. How is the list connected? Should it not be inside the () also?

Comment: Things inside of () or [] do not need the continuation character.  So, that is why it is on some lines and not others. :)   A simple solution not to use it at all, is to wrap the entire command in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try merging the result of the pivot table on the initial dataframe:

```
df = pd.merge(df, 
     df.pivot_table(index= 'Time', 
                    values = ['Amount', 'Total', 'Fee'], 
                    aggfunc = 'sum'), 
     how = 'outer')
```

If this is not what you want to have (as your title suggests, but your question is somewhat confusing), maybe you just calculate the mean-weighted price from the columns in your pivot table.

Comment: This was not quite what I was trying to do (also I could have worded it a bit more clear), but appreciate you taking the time to try and help out, much appreciated :)